# Repaint all cells with "white" color fill to "no fill"

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've inherited a spreadsheet in Excel which inconsistently uses "no fill" or "white fill" for most cells (*most* -- there also exist other cells with other colors, i.e. for specific input assumptions or output values).

I'd love to be able to replace all the cells with "no fill" with "white fill" (or perhaps depending on how it looks, those with "white fill" to "no fill").

Is there any easy way to do this?  (I'm on Windows if that helps).

Thanks,
/YGA

Comment: see this: https://www.customguide.com/excel/find-and-replace-formatting-in-excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select `Ctrl + H` set the **Find What** format **Fill** to `White` and **Replace with** format **Fill** to `No Color`:

[image]

[image]